# Riley number three can do it all by himself!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is my third Riley riddle! Hope you like it!

> My prefix is knee backwards,
>
> My suffix is my opposite,
>
> My infix is the end,
>
> And altogether I work alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is a stretch and a half, but are you

> INDEPENDENT?

My prefix is knee backwards,

> Knee phonetically is NI, backwards is IN.

My suffix is my opposite,

> The opposite of independent is DEPENDENT.

My infix is the end,

> The word END is an infix in the word indepENDent.

And altogether I work alone.

> INDEPENDENT people work alone.

Comment: Correct! You guys are fast! Gotta wait 3 minutes before I accept though.

Comment: @YoutRied **El-Guest** // is the best! // "Where's a Riley/Rebus?" he'd request! :D

Comment: @user477343 You’re too funny!! I appreciate that poem, too kind of you :D